# c# merging two text files based on a common id

Tags: c#

i have two text files like below. I have something common like ID_1 deg & End and i need to copy and merge the data between this to a new file.

**First file:**

```
ID_1  deg
12212  -45.22 -22.66
155566 -22.02  66.55
222312  22.56 -33.54
End
ID_2  deg
12232   35.22 -62.16
355526 -32.02 -26.55
62665   21.56 -2.53
End
```

**Second file:**

```
ID_1  deg
22332  -35.22 -52.66
155566  -6.02  33.55
222312 -62.56 -3.50
End
ID_2  deg
52232   23.22 -61.16
955526 -33.02 -66.55
12665  -33.56  -1.53
End
```

output(after merged) file:

```
ID_1  deg
12212  -45.22 -22.66
155566 -22.02  66.55
222312  22.56 -33.54
12232   35.22 -62.16
355526 -32.02 -26.55
62665   21.56  -2.53
End
ID_2  deg
12232   35.22 -62.16
355526 -32.02 -26.55
62665    21.56 -2.53
52232   23.22 -61.16
955526 -33.02 -66.55
12665  -33.56  -1.53
End
```

i want to merge both text files by common Id_1(name) and end with considering duplicate data between ID_"".
i am very new to the programming, if i can get at least some idea how to start in above case.

Comment: It seems your merged ID_1 has data form file1 and file2, typo or some missing requirement?

Comment: ID_1 & ID_2 are in both files. the requirement is: to merge data between ID_1 and End, and same between ID_2 and End.

Comment: Are you at least reading the files yet? As you .ReadLine you can either rip them into objects or place them in a dictionary... then go the other way and write the dictionary to a file... there’s def a couple ways to approach this but your workflow will be Read > organize > write. Do you have any code you can share in dotfiddle? It doesn’t have to be with physical files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, since you know what the data looks like:

```
string input_file1 = "input_file1_path_here";
string input_file2 = "input_file2_path_here";
string outputfile = "your_output_file_path_here";
int start = 0;
string lst1 = string.Empty;
string lst1b = string.Empty;
string lst2 = string.Empty;
string lst2b = string.Empty;
string content = File.ReadAllText(input_file1);
lst1 = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("ID_2"));
lst1 = lst1.Substring(0, lst1.IndexOf("End"));
start = content.IndexOf("ID_2");
lst2 = content.Substring(start);
lst2 = lst2.Substring(0, lst2.IndexOf("End")).Trim();
content = File.ReadAllText(input_file2);
lst1b = content.Substring(content.IndexOf("deg") + 5, content.IndexOf("ID_2"));
lst1b = lst1b.Substring(0, lst1b.IndexOf("End") + 3);
lst1 += lst1b + Environment.NewLine;
start = content.IndexOf("ID_2");
lst2b = content.Substring(start);
lst2b = lst2b.Substring(lst2b.IndexOf("deg") + 3);
lst2 += lst2b;
File.WriteAllText(outputfile, lst1 + lst2);
```